# Matrix valued system of equations with right and left product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, positive-definite, kronecker-product

Let $J$ be a real valued $2\times 2$ matrix with determinant equal to 1. The eigenvalues of $J$ are complex in general. Let $Q$ be a $2\times 2$ matrix satisfying
$$J^T Q J = Q$$

**Question:** Does there exist a $Q$ which is symmetric positive-definite?

My work so far:

I have found a solution for $Q$ by using the [vec operator](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) and the kronecker product. Taking the $\text{vec}$ of both sides of the above equations yields
$$(J\otimes J^T) \text{vec}(Q) = \text{vec}(Q)$$

Notice $\text{vec}(Q)$ is an eigenvector of $(J\otimes J^T)$ with eigenvalue 1. This eigenvector exists because $J$ has determinant one, so $(J\otimes J^T)$ has at least two eigenvalues equal to one. The multiplicity 2 on the eigenvalue should give us two degrees of freedom to ensure that $Q$ is symmetric positive definite.

Comment: so, what do you get for  $J=\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
4 & 13 \\ 
-1 & -3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\; \; \;  ? \; \; $

Comment: @WillJagy it seems that I can only get indefinite Q for your example. Care to share how you came up with the example?

Comment: I do the easier direction, given symmetric indefinite matrix of integers, that  would be your $Q,$  but where the determinant is not minus a square,  there is a recipe that gives all possible $J$ (also integers)  in terms of a Pell equation.  Your question suggested complex eigenvalues  for $J,$  with determinant $1$   that says trace $1,-1,0$  Still all integers, from $J$ the same number theory stuff can lead to $Q$  but usually an indefinite form.

Comment: In addition, I have found that for Symplectic maps $J$, $Q = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is a solution